# WooCommerce Cart - Conditional Items categories validation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, cart

We have an **exclusive category X** and others **regular categories Y**. What I would like:

- When someone orders anything from  **category X**, other category items cannot be added to cart and should display a warning
- **category Y** products should not be mixed with **X**.

How could I achieve that?

I got this code from other post, but its outdated and not satisfactory:

```
<?php

 // Enforce single parent category items in cart at a time based on first item in cart
function get_product_top_level_category ( $product_id ) {

    $product_terms            =  get_the_terms ( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    $product_category         =  $product_terms[0]->parent;
    $product_category_term    =  get_term ( $product_category, 'product_cat' );
    $product_category_parent  =  $product_category_term->parent;
    $product_top_category     =  $product_category_term->term_id;

    while ( $product_category_parent  !=  0 ) {
            $product_category_term    =  get_term ( $product_category_parent, 'product_cat' );
            $product_category_parent  =  $product_category_term->parent;
            $product_top_category     =  $product_category_term->term_id;
    }

    return $product_top_category;
}

add_filter ( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'restrict_cart_to_single_category' );
function restrict_cart_to_single_category() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_contents    =  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart( );
    $cart_item_keys   =  array_keys ( $cart_contents );
    $cart_item_count  =  count ( $cart_item_keys );

    // Do nothing if the cart is empty
    // Do nothing if the cart only has one item
    if ( ! $cart_contents || $cart_item_count == 1 ) {
            return null;
    }

    // Multiple Items in cart
    $first_item                    =  $cart_item_keys[0];
    $first_item_id                 =  $cart_contents[$first_item]['product_id'];
    $first_item_top_category       =  get_product_top_level_category ( $first_item_id );
    $first_item_top_category_term  =  get_term ( $first_item_top_category, 'product_cat' );
    $first_item_top_category_name  =  $first_item_top_category_term->name;

    // Now we check each subsequent items top-level parent category
    foreach ( $cart_item_keys as $key ) {
            if ( $key  ==  $first_item ) {
                    continue;
            }
            else {
                    $product_id            =  $cart_contents[$key]['product_id'];
                    $product_top_category  =  get_product_top_level_category( $product_id );

                    if ( $product_top_category  !=  $first_item_top_category ) {
                            $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity ( $key, 0, true );
                            $mismatched_categories  =  1;
                    }
            }
    }

    // we really only want to display this message once for anyone, including those that have carts already prefilled
    if ( isset ( $mismatched_categories ) ) {
            echo '<p class="woocommerce-error">Only one category allowed in cart at a time.<br />You are currently allowed only <strong>'.$first_item_top_category_name.'</strong> items in your cart.<br />To order a different category empty your cart first.</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated *(2019)*

Like everything is turning around your exclusive category **`category X`**, you need to use a conditional for this category.

And you have chance because there is a special function that you can use in combination with woocommerce product categories. Lets say that `**cat_x**` is the slug for your exclusive category, as you know it yet **`product_cat`** is the argument to get products categories.

So with **`has_term ()`** conditional function, you are going to use this:

```
if ( has_term ('cat_x', 'product_cat', $item_id ) ) { // or $product_id
    // doing something when product item has 'cat_x'
} else {
    // doing something when product item has NOT 'cat_x'
}
```

We need to run the cart items 2 times in a foreach loop:

- To detect if there is a **`cat_x`** item in that car.
- To remove  other items if **`cat_x`** is detected for one item in the cart and to fire the right messages.

In the code below, I have changed to a more useful hook. This hook will check what you have in your cart. The idea is to removed other categories items in the cart when there is a 'cat_x' item added in cart.

The code is well commented. At the end you will find different notices that are fired. You will need to put your real text in each.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'checking_cart_items' );
function checking_cart_items() {
    // Set your product category slug
    $category = 'cat_x';

    $number_of_items = sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() );
    $found  = false; // Initializing
    $notice = ''; // Initializing

    if ( $number_of_items > 0 ) {

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

            // Detecting if the defined category is in cart
            if ( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                $found = true;
                break; // Stop the loop
            }
        }

        // Re-loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

            if ( $found ) // If the defined product category is in cart
            { 
                if ( $number_of_items == 1 ) { // only one defined product category
                    if ( empty( $notice ) ){
                        $notice = '1';
                    }
                }
                if ( $number_of_items >= 2 ) { // The defined product category + other categories in cart

                    // removing other categories items from cart
                    if ( ! has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key ); // removing item from cart
                        if ( empty( $notice ) || $notice == '1' ){
                            $notice = '2';
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else { // Only other categories items

                if ( empty( $notice ) ){
                    $notice = '3';
                }
            }
        }

        // Firing woocommerce notices
        if ( $notice == '1' ) { // message for an 'cat_x' item only (alone)
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<p class="woocommerce-error">bla bla bla one category X item in the cart</p>' ), 'success' );
        } elseif ( $notice == '2' ) { // message for an 'cat_x' item and other ones => removed other ones 
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<p class="woocommerce-error">bla bla bla ther is already category X in the cart => Other category items has been removed</p>' ), 'error' );
        } elseif ( $notice == '3' ) { // message for other categories items (if needed)
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<p class="woocommerce-error">bla bla bla NOT category X in the cart</p>' ), 'success' );
        }
    }
}
```

Is not possible for me to really test this code (but it doesn't throws errors)…

---

**@edit**

We can use something else than notices… everything is possible. But it's a good starting solution, to fine tune.

You will need to replace **`'cat_x'`** by your real category slug *(in the beginning)*…

Comment: looks like i got the solution, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer in 2020**

Recently, I need almost the same requirement. But instead of a single category, I have to check if the item is in a group of categories.

Consider that I have 6 categories. I will group 6 categories into 3 groups. My customer can only purchase items in a single category group (but multiple categories) in a single order.

The code snippet is given below.

```
function sa45er_category_group_validation($valid, $product_id, $quantity) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
         return $valid;
    }
    
    $target_cat_group = array(
        array(17,20), // Update your product category
        array(19,18), // Update your product category
    );
    
    $this_product_terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($this_product_terms as $term) {
        $this_product_cat_ids[] = $term->term_id; 
    }        
            
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->get_ID(), 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $cart_cat_ids[] = $term->term_id;  
        }       
    }
    
    $all_cats = array_merge($this_product_cat_ids,$cart_cat_ids);
    
    $result = array();
    foreach($target_cat_group as $target_cat_group_item){
            
        $intrsct = array_intersect($all_cats, $target_cat_group_item);
        
        if( !empty( $intrsct ) ){
            $result[] = $intrsct;
        }
            
    }
    
    if(count($result) > 1){
        wc_add_notice( 'You can\'t add this product with your current cart items.', 'error' );
        return false;
    }
    
    return $valid;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'sa45er_category_group_validation',10,3);
```

Comment: How does this work if I need to stop 2 categories from mixing? I tried adapting $target_cat_group in your snippet to "array(17), array(20)" and even "array(17,20)" but results are incorrect in both situations. Products from child categories are not taken into account and a product from the first array can be added if a product from the second array is already in the cart but not the other way around.