# WooCommerce - Limit Purchases to 1 Product Category at a time

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am wanting to limit customers to be able to purchase multiple products from **one** **product** **category** **per** **order**.

I have had a look at this question - [Limit purchase to 1 product category at the time in WooCommerce 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746134/limit-purchase-to-1-product-category-at-the-time-in-woocommerce-3-0) - but the answer only allows users to purchase one product from one category, which is not what I want.

For Example -

- Customer can purchase socks and hats in the same order as they are categorised as 'accessories'.
- However if they try to add a top to their current basket which has socks and hats in, it will not let them add it as the top is categorised as 'clothing'. A message should pop up telling them this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just pass true in the condition and add else where u pass false thats all

Comment: @MartinMirchev - Thanks for the comment, however I am unsure what you are meaning. Wouldn't that outcome still only allow only one product from one category? I'm wanting multiple products from one category